# Internet Explorer not loading css on VS 2013. Chrome does

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, internet-explorer

I've a MVC 5 project built with VS 2013 and bootstrap 3. I created a couple of classes in the Site.css file, mostly to change color, font, etc, and they were working fine. But now, it doesn't work anymore in IE 11 although it still works in Chrome. What  I'm saying is that the IE ignores the classes in the Site.css.

I'm using all defaults from VS 2013. I've not changed the bundle configuration and I verify that it includes the Site.css

Just to make sure, I created a simple project with one label and a class to change its color. It works in Chrome and not in IE.

This is the BundleConfig

```
   public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",    // ** NEW for Bootstrap Datepicker
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",  // ** NEW for Bootstrap Datepicker
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you browse the CSS source in IE, do you see the class style definitions there? I'm wondering if it's Internet Explorer's cache that's preventing you from seeing the changes.

Comment: @Richiban Yes, if I click the refresh button it works.Thanks!!!  But how is it going to be in the real world? Will the users need to refresh the page also? Is there anyway around?

Comment: Bundling should really take care of the caching for you, by adding a version number to the URL of the CSS file. What bundling solution are you using?

Comment: I updated the question with a copy of the Bundle. I'm keeping the standard convention used by VS 2013, but I dont see any version number in the URL

Comment: According to http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification your URLs should have a version number appended as a query string. Follow that guide, making sure that your views are referencing the CSS via    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css").

Answer (score 0):

same problem I had , The Problem Be In Compatibility of internet explorer 10 and 11
if you can install older version will work fine